# check point ssl network extender installation mac os safari

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, checkpoint

SSL Network Extender fails to launch.

launching SSL Network Extender fails with "**failed to download**" on safari.

I think there is a solution but they do not share it public.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

In checkpoint user center Solution ID   sk96108.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a download link?

Comment: There is no download link. When you authenticate, it starts to install application to your pc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: From the [Safari 12 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/safari/whats-new/):

> Legacy NPAPI Plug-ins
>
> - Removed support for running legacy NPAPI plug-ins other than Adobe Flash.

**This means that plugins such as Java and Silverlight will no longer work in Safari 12.** This answer still works for Safari 11 and earlier. For a solution that works on newer versions, see [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52422602/3398839) (which uses an old version of Firefox).

---

Simply **hold down "alt/option"** and click on the Java trust settings for the relevant website, deselect "Run in Safe Mode", and click "Trust" in the dialog that pops up:

[image: demonstration]

Source: [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202819).

Comment: Safari does not support Java anymore. :( . It does not work with updated version.