# Update to Safari 12.0 - Java Plug-in no longer listed

Tags: java, plugins, safari

After updating to *Safari Version 12.0*, the Java Plug-in under *Safari > Preferences... > Websites > Plug-ins* is no longer listed and therefore Java Applets cannot be ran in unsafe mode. Is there a way to enable the Java Plug-in or to run Java Applets anyway (on macOS)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Safari 12 no longer supports java. As someone mentioned on the apple discussion forums one of the workarounds is to switch to Firefox version [v52.9ESR](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/52.9.0esr/mac/). It is important to (quickly) disable updates within the Firefox preferences or it will update to a newer version that also doesn't support Java. Worked for me.

Comment: this is probably the simplest workaround..thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Safari 12 removes support for running legacy NPAPI plug-ins other than Adobe Flash, according to: https://developer.apple.com/safari/whats-new/

Comment: A screenshot of the page from that time is at https://www.techhelpkb.com/java-support-in-safari-12/